# When I am using command line arguments, why is python counting my file name as a value?

Tags: python, command-line, arguments

I have tried to fix it and have looked over my code many times, but nothing really seems wrong.

I had unpacked the module to 3 values and tried run the program, but it gave me the error that I was giving too many values:

PS C:\dir1> python exlp.py ramen lucid chubby

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "exlp.py", line 54, in

```
ramen, lucid, chubby = argv
```

ValueError: too many values to unpack

After a while I figured out that it was counting the file name as a value. I have no clue why this is happening, but here is my code:

```
  from sys import argv

sakura, ramen, lucid, chubby = argv

print "You love...", sakura
print "You like to eat...", ramen
print "Your dreams are...", lucid
print "You are...", Naruto

print raw_input('Do you know someone named Naruto?')
```

Thank you!

Comment: it is standard behaviour since language C was created about 45 yeas ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's [what it does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

> ### `sys.argv`
>
> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python
>   script. `argv[0]` is the script name (it is operating system dependent
>   whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed
>   using the [`-c`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c) command line option to the interpreter, `argv[0]` is set to
>   the string `'-c'`. If no script name was passed to the Python
>   interpreter, `argv[0]` is the empty string.
>
> To loop over the standard input, or the list of files given on the
>   command line, see the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module.

Either account for that value or slice that list:

```
_, ramen, lucid, chubby = argv # option 1
ramen, lucid, chubby = argv[1:] # option 2
```

Comment: Would the "_" appear when I run the program in option 1?

Comment: @PenguinBros - It's just a variable name, conventionally used for throwaway variables.